# Java <-> Scala convertion - "value is not a member of"

Tags: java, scala, type-conversion

I have a problem with Scala code with Java methods.

It is calling:

```
value getDepth is not a member of amqpManagment.utils.data.ChessObject
var depth: Int = chessObjects.getDepth()
                                  ^
```

However i use getDepth in many other places in Java code and it works fine.
Also after put that code it was working in InteliJ by few hours which is weird but maybe project didnt rebuild itself after that change...

However InteliJ shows code is okay, but during compiling it shows that error. Rebuilding by InteliJ or terminal doesnt help.

**Scala code:**

```
import amqpManagment.utils.data.ChessObject
object ChessScheduler {

  // DEPTH GAME
  def startGameWithDepthRule(chessObject: ChessObject) : Integer = 
  {
    ...
    val depth: Int = chessObjects.getDepth()
    ...
  }
}
```

**Java Code:**

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class ChessObject {
    private Integer depth;
    ...
}
```

**build.sbt**

```
import sbt.Keys._
import sbt.Level

name := "ChessEngineModuler"
logLevel := Level.Warn

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.12.2"
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is that error message accurate? Is there a mistake in the copy-n-paste? There's a dot missing: `chessObjects` `getDepth()`

Comment: Hello @jwvh, yeah it is , i just made a typo in this question, it is about that code. I will edit it now. Thanks :)

Comment: You have `CheeJSONObject` in scala, but `ChessObject` in java. These are different classes. Perhaps, the former has `getDepth`, and the latter does not?

Comment: Heyo @Dima , you have right but it is also not the problem :/ i just change name of that to do not bother you about JSONs created from this file as it is local problem. Sorry for inconvenience :( I think it is something not seen on first place as InteliJ didnt see the problem, only compilation is not proper and fail :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hello @Chenna Reddy :)

Thank you for your post, It seems it was problem with Lombok indeed. However after your answer i realised it was a problem because Scala code was compiled before Java one.

I check three solutions cause i had added dependency and Annotation Processor On.

1. First solution is just adding Getters and Setters to Java class not by the Lombok, however it is ugly solution
2. Second Solution is just adding in Files -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Scala Compiler -> Compile Order -> Java then Scala.
3. Third one is set in **build.sbt** -> `compileOrder := CompileOrder.JavaThenScala`

I think 3rd is the best one if we want deploy that code somewhere :)

Comment: FWIW, I love the first solution.
Or just make the variable public.

Comment: Solution #2 worked for me. Mine was originally set to mixed.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using [lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) for auto generation of getters. Please add lombok dependency.

```
libraryDependencies += "org.projectlombok" % "lombok" % "1.16.16"
```

Above step is not required if you are building Java project seperately and that project has lombok as a compile time dependency. Then generated jar file must have all the getters already.

Regarding why Intellij shows error sometimes, its possible that you didn't enable annotation processing from Files -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Annotation Processors.